# Getting numbers separate from letters from a field in Crystal Reports SAP when the format changes

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm sorry if this has already been solved, I cant seem to find anything for my specific issue.

We have job numbers that use the following formats: **011111**, **11111A**, and **11A111**. For all of these, I need to export to a new field that just reads **11111**. I know I can use right`({table.job},5)` for the first, `left({table.job},5)` for the second, or even `val({table.job})` but I can not find anything that works to get just the numbers out of the last format.

I have tried using `val({table.job})` but it only gives me the first set before the letter. I have tried using the `join` function and using `left` 2 + `right` 3, but I'm still new to this and I'm not certain that I have been using the correct syntax.

I also tried using an array to find the third character to see if it was a specific letter, but it is not accepting the code, and I scrapped it.

When I typed all of it out, I kept getting the error **"The ) is missing"** but no words were highlighted and I have double checked the opening and closing parenthesis. I know it might be something simple, but I am stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
local stringvar JobN := "011A111";
local stringvar result := "";
local numbervar i;

For i := 1 to Len(JobN) do
(IF isnumeric(JobN[i]) Then result := result + JobN[i]) ;

ToText(Val(result),0,"");
```